# Dockerized FastAPI App Fails with /.venv/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/home'

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I got this up and running locally, and was able to get it working with Docker when I put `command: uvicorn backend.main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000` in `docker-compose.yaml`; and I didn't have the `uvicorn` call in `main.py`.

Of course when I made further changes, particularly placing the `uvicorn` call in `main.py`, things went down hill.  Now I get the following Docker error:

```
/.venv/bin/python: can't find '__main__' module in '/home'
```

Please note the `backend/main.py` file below does work successfully when I run it locally; but of course I have an issue with Docker.

Here's what I have thus far:

**Folder Structure**

```
├── backend
│   ├── .docker
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── .env
│   ├── main.py
├──docker-compose.yaml
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/home
```

**backend/.docker/Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.11.3-slim-buster as base

# Setup env
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8

# Prevent Python from writing .pyc files to disk
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER 1
# Ensure Python output is sent straight to terminal 
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

FROM base AS python-deps

# Update container essentials
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    gcc postgresql-client \
  && apt-get clean

# Install pipenv
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv

# Install python dependencies in /.venv
COPY Pipfile .
COPY Pipfile.lock .
RUN PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT=1 pipenv install --deploy

FROM base AS runtime

# Copy virtual env from python-deps stage
COPY --from=python-deps /.venv /.venv
ENV PATH="/.venv/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /home

# Install application into container
COPY . .

CMD python . main.py
```

**backend/.env**

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=i_need_help

ENV=dev

APP_MODULE=app
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=8000
```

**backend/main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI(
  title="I Need Help",
  version="0",
)

@app.get("/health")
async def health() -> JSONResponse:
  return { "message": "OK" }

if __name__ == "__main__":
  import os
  import uvicorn

  uvicorn.run(
    os.getenv("APP_MODULE"),
    host=os.getenv("HOST"),
    port=int(os.getenv("PORT")),
    reload=True
  )
```

All help is appreciated - thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CMD python . main.py

This looks incorrect. When you provide a directory (`.` is `/home` in this case) as the first argument to `python` it will look for a `__main__.py` file in that directory and attempt to execute it within the namespace of the provided directory. You have no `__main__.py` file anywhere -- this is the source of the error message you are receiving.

The string `main.py` is simply being provided as an argument in this case.

You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
CMD ["python", "backend/main.py"]
```

---

Alternatively, create the file `backend/__main__.py` something like this:

```py
# backend/__main__.py
import uvicorn, os
uvicorn.run(
    'backend.main:app',
    host=os.getenv("HOST"),
    port=int(os.getenv("PORT")),
    reload=True
)
```

Then you can run your project as a package by doing this in your dockerfile:

```
CMD ["python", "-m", "backend"]
```

Comment: Thanks @sytech!  That was it.  I went with your first suggestion for ```CMD``` and updated `.env` to ```APP_MODULE=main:app```.